# When reading in data from a zip-file in R, it corrupts the previous read-in data

Tags: r, readr

My goal is to read in zip files directly from the web (opentransportdata.swiss). Each zip file contains multiple .txt files. In my example I am trying to retrieve the data of the routes.txt file.

So my code is the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

# links
tt_url <- c("https://opentransportdata.swiss/de/dataset/7787e566-03cf-4cd5-8a66-b5af08547e74/resource/4bc9d75e-cdd7-4020-8ee1-9dd494ee8b4c/download/gtfsfp20162016-11-30.zip", 
            "https://opentransportdata.swiss/de/dataset/587ecf41-eb18-448a-8073-7076bc3cbfeb/resource/e499a630-4e65-4e00-8522-26c5c78b88ca/download/gtfsfp20172017-12-06.zip")

# download zip files
f_get_data <- function(i, data){
  url <- tt_url[i]
  zip_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
  download.file(url, zip_file, mode = "wb")
  df <- read_delim(unzip(zip_file, files = data), delim = ",") %>%
    mutate(year = i + 2015)
  return(df)
}

test_1 <- f_get_data(1, "routes.txt")
head(test_1)
test_2 <- f_get_data(2, "routes.txt")
head(test_2)
head(test_1)
```

If one applies the function f_get_data(1, "routes.txt) the first time, the retrieved df ,test_1, is correct.

```
head(test_1)
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  route_id    agency_id route_short_name route_long_name route_type route_color route_text_color  year
  <chr>       <lgl>     <chr>            <lgl>                <dbl> <lgl>       <lgl>            <dbl>
1 11-21-j16-1 NA        021              NA                       3 NA          NA                2016
2 11-22-j16-1 NA        022              NA                       3 NA          NA                2016
3 16-22-j16-1 NA        022              NA                       3 NA          NA                2016
4 11-25-j16-1 NA        025              NA                       3 NA          NA                2016
5 11-41-j16-1 NA        041              NA                       3 NA          NA                2016
6 11-42-j16-1 NA        042              NA                       3 NA          NA                2016
```

If I go onto the next period with f_get_data(2, "routes.txt), the retrieved df, test_2, is also correct.

BUT, after I completed my second iteration, the first df, test_1, corrupts itself:

```
> head(test_2)
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  route_id    agency_id route_short_name route_long_name route_desc route_type  year
  <chr>       <chr>     <chr>            <lgl>           <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>
1 79-0-j17-1  881       00               NA              Bus               700  2017
2 11-61-j17-1 7031      061              NA              Bus               700  2017
3 11-62-j17-1 7031      062              NA              Bus               700  2017
4 24-64-j17-1 801       064              NA              Bus               700  2017
5 24-65-j17-1 801       065              NA              Bus               700  2017
6 24-66-j17-1 801       066              NA              Bus               700  2017

> head(test_1)
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  route_id             agency_id route_short_name route_long_name route_type route_color route_text_color  year
  <chr>                <lgl>     <chr>            <lgl>                <dbl> <lgl>       <lgl>            <dbl>
1 ",\"00\",\"\",\"Bus" NA        "00\"\r\n"       NA                      NA NA          NA                2016
2 "7031\",\"061\",\""  NA        "us\",\""        NA                      NA NA          NA                2016
3 "7-1\",\"7031\",\""  NA        ",\"\",\""       NA                      NA NA          NA                2016
4 "-64-j17-1\",\"8"    NA        "064"            NA                      NA NA          NA                2016
5 "\r\n\"24-65-j17-"   NA        "801\","         NA                      NA NA          NA                2016
6 "700\r\n24-66"       NA        "-1\",\""        NA                      NA NA          NA                2016
```

Does anyone know why and especially how this happens? In my opinion, after I have assigned the retrieved data of my function to a certain data frame, it should be independent of the later use of my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the default behavior of the `read_delim()` function.  In order to improve performance the data is loaded in a lazy manner, meaning the data is only accessed when needed.
So in actuality the return value from "f_get_data" is just a pointer to the data. In this case it is a pointer your temporary file which is overwritten on each call to the function.

To solve this, set lazy to *FALSE* in the `read_delim()` function call.

```
df <- read_delim(unzip(zip_file, files = data), delim = ",", lazy=FALSE) %>%
      mutate(year = i + 2015)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot replicate this, not coding tidyversish though. Perhaps try my code.

```
> # links
> tt_url <- c("https://opentransportdata.swiss/de/dataset/7787e566-03cf-4cd5-8a66-b5af08547e74/resource/4bc9d75e-cdd7-4020-8ee1-9dd494ee8b4c/download/gtfsfp20162016-11-30.zip", 
+             "https://opentransportdata.swiss/de/dataset/587ecf41-eb18-448a-8073-7076bc3cbfeb/resource/e499a630-4e65-4e00-8522-26c5c78b88ca/download/gtfsfp20172017-12-06.zip")
> # download zip files
> f_get_data <- function(i, data) {
+   on.exit(unlink(temp))  ## don't forget to unlink your tempfiles!
+   temp <- tempfile(fileext='.zip')
+   url <- tt_url[i]
+   download.file(url, temp, mode = "wb")
+   df <- read.csv(unzip(temp, files=data)) |>
+     transform(year=i + 2015)
+   return(df)
+ }
> 
> test_1 <- f_get_data(1, "routes.txt")
trying URL 'https://opentransportdata.swiss/de/dataset/7787e566-03cf-4cd5-8a66-b5af08547e74/resource/4bc9d75e-cdd7-4020-8ee1-9dd494ee8b4c/download/gtfsfp20162016-11-30.zip'
downloaded 26.1 MB

> head(test_1)
     route_id agency_id route_short_name route_long_name route_type route_color route_text_color year
1 11-21-j16-1        NA              021              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
2 11-22-j16-1        NA              022              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
3 16-22-j16-1        NA              022              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
4 11-25-j16-1        NA              025              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
5 11-41-j16-1        NA              041              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
6 11-42-j16-1        NA              042              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
> test_2 <- f_get_data(2, "routes.txt")
trying URL 'https://opentransportdata.swiss/de/dataset/587ecf41-eb18-448a-8073-7076bc3cbfeb/resource/e499a630-4e65-4e00-8522-26c5c78b88ca/download/gtfsfp20172017-12-06.zip'
downloaded 81.1 MB

> head(test_2)
     route_id agency_id route_short_name route_long_name route_desc route_type year
1  79-0-j17-1       881               00              NA        Bus        700 2017
2 11-61-j17-1      7031              061              NA        Bus        700 2017
3 11-62-j17-1      7031              062              NA        Bus        700 2017
4 24-64-j17-1       801              064              NA        Bus        700 2017
5 24-65-j17-1       801              065              NA        Bus        700 2017
6 24-66-j17-1       801              066              NA        Bus        700 2017
> head(test_1)
     route_id agency_id route_short_name route_long_name route_type route_color route_text_color year
1 11-21-j16-1        NA              021              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
2 11-22-j16-1        NA              022              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
3 16-22-j16-1        NA              022              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
4 11-25-j16-1        NA              025              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
5 11-41-j16-1        NA              041              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
6 11-42-j16-1        NA              042              NA          3          NA               NA 2016
>
```

Comment: The problem lies with the readr package. @Dave2e said, that readr reads the data in a "lazy manner", which needs to be set to laze = FALSE. I think by using read.csv() (as in your case) instead of the readr equivalent, this solves the problem as well. Thanks for your input.